# Link multiple changesets at once to User Story in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, changeset

I have a User Story in TFS 2010 and I want to link to it all the changesets that are relevant for the User Story.

So in the User Story, I go to the `All Links` tab, click on `Link to`, change the link type from `Child` to `Changeset`, click on `Browse`, fill in my name under `By user:` and click on `Find`. I am now presented with a list of all my changesets.

My problem is that I have several dozen changesets that I want to attach to the User Story, but that I can't do a multiple select. I have to select a changeset, and click twice on `OK`to link to it. And then I have to repeat the whole process for the next one. And so on...

This gets boring rather quickly. What I ideally want to do is in the `Find Changesets` window to do a search on keywords in the commit comments, select all the changesets that are relevant and link to all of them at once.

Is there a way to achieve this in TFS 2010, or is there another way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you can do this **programmatically** using the [Team Foundation Server API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Here's an example:

```
var server = new TeamFoundationServer(serverName);
var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)server.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
var project = workItemStore.Projects[projectName];

var userStoryId = 9;
var changeSetsIds = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var userStory = project.Store.GetWorkItem(userStoryId);

foreach (var changeSetId in changeSetsIds)
{
    var changeSetLink = new RelatedLink(changeSetId);
    userStory.Links.Add(changeSetLink);
}

userStory.Save();
```

**See also:**

- [Automation to relate TFS work items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jampick/archive/2009/09/21/automation-to-relate-tfs-work-items.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The linking part can be done as @[Enrico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8323379/728929) suggests. 
Your other only challenge is to discover and select the appropriate changesets in order to fill Enricos' `changeSetsIds`.

I 'm not aware of way to implement this using TFS-SDK, yet there are [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925875/how-do-i-find-and-view-a-tfs-changeset-by-comment-text) to do this:
You either pipe the output of a `tfpt searchcs`, or make use of [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3f65dee8-5a44-4771-929b-26531c482fbf) VS extension. The VS extension operates even with regex, but it's copy/paste is somehow not optimum.