# Searching for all TFS changesets based on a check-in Comment

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to search TFS using PowerShell to find all changesets that contain some sub-string in the check-in comment? I'd like to see the individual files in all the changesets in one view. In my case I am searching for all changesets that contain a defect number e.g. 'D-12345'.

I tried the example as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/960724/787157). But running ...

```
tf history $/MyCodeRepo/Trunk -r /noprompt /format:detailed | ? { $_.comment -like *D-12345* }
```

... gives me several errors:

- You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the
  '-like' operator.
- You must provide a value expression on the
  right-hand side of the '*' operator.
- Unexpected token 'D-12345*' in
  expression or statement.

I then tried putting quotes around the search string but that just returned no results.

I have TFS power tools installed and I know you can use searchcs to search by Comment but you have to open each changeset individually.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Does it have to be command line? I can knock something up using the API in Linqpad in about 2 minutes :)

Comment: Dumb question, but you *are* running that command in PowerShell, not from a normal command prompt?

Comment: Have you tried using the tfs snapins that come with the powertools?

Comment: Hi @Mike, no I haven't. I'm not familiar with TFS snapins. How would I go about using them? What can they be used for? Thanks

Comment: The snap-ins come with the tfs power tools (i'm familiar with 2010 version). You must run them from an x86 prompt. Do a Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell to add it. There is a Powershell entry in the power tools programs folder (in start menu). And you can do a lot of the things that tf.exe can do like query history.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
tf history $/ -r | ? { $_.comment -like *D-12345* }
```

You can also try with `fpt searchcs`

Comment: Hi @Aghilas. Afraid that doesn't work. It's pretty much what I had tried in the original post but without the `/noprompt` and  `/format:detailed` switches. I know about `searchcs` in TFS powertools but what is `fpt`? Thanks ...

Comment: Hi Gavin fpt it's another extension in power tool

Comment: On my machine at least, it is `tfpt searchcs` not `fpt searchcs`

Comment: Yes, it's `tfpt searchcs`. Thanks for this find - it does exactly what I need!

Comment: i'am happy to help you Robert

Comment: On Windows 10, the above does not work. You have to remove the '.comment' portion for the command to work.

Comment: '?' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.