# TFS 2013: How to get changeset comments into a text file?

Tags: tfs

I'd like to get all changeset comments into a simple text file (to generate a changelog automatically).  I tried doing this by querying TFS tables in SQL, but it's an undocumented black box...

I read one post to run something like this:

```
tf history $/ -r
```

I got the latest TFS 2013 power tools, but that includes "tfpt" instead of "tf".  "tfpt searchcs" opens a gui even if given command line arguments.

Does anyone know how to accomplish what I'm requesting?

EDIT: I was referring to this [How do I find and view a TFS changeset by comment text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925875/how-do-i-find-and-view-a-tfs-changeset-by-comment-text), and the accepted answer states

> With the Power Tools installed:
>
> tf history $/ -r | ? { $_.comment -like *findme* }

So I assumed power tools had to be installed... Apparently however, it seems tf.exe is INCLUDED with Visual Studio as it's located in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

(for me at least).  Anyway, I tried running:

```
tf history $/myprojectpath -r
```

and that too, opens a ui... on a whim however, I tried to redirect output:

```
tf history $/myprojectpath -r >> file.txt
```

and that seemed to do exactly what I needed...

Asked and answered... sorry gang :/

Comment: Best to reply with your answer as an actual answer.  You can accept your own answer after a few days as the correct one.  That will make it clearer that this question does have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was referring to [How do I find and view a TFS changeset by comment text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925875/how-do-i-find-and-view-a-tfs-changeset-by-comment-text), and the accepted answer states

```
With the Power Tools installed:

tf history $/ -r | ? { $_.comment -like findme }
```

So I assumed power tools had to be installed... Apparently however, it seems tf.exe is INCLUDED with Visual Studio as it's located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
```

(for me at least). Anyway, I tried running:

```
tf history $/myprojectpath -r
```

and that too, opens a ui... on a whim however, I tried to redirect output:

```
tf history $/myprojectpath -r >> file.txt
```

and that seemed to do exactly what I needed...

Asked and answered... sorry gang :/

Comment: tf.exe comes with Team Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Novox for this clarifying contribution. Bizarre that `tf /?` says nothing about it.