# Search changeset checkin comments on Visual Studio or Visual Studio online

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I want to go through my changesets and search for a specific checkin/changeset comments on Visual studio 2013 or on Visual Studio Online. How can I do this? On github is very easy to do this but I am struggling on VS online.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/925875/292060

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find Changeset By Comment extension for Visual Studio
https://findchangeset.codeplex.com/releases/view/99003

For Visual Studio 2013
http://developer.azurewebsites.net/2014/08/find-changeset-by-comment-2013-for-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 13):

If you have [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) installed, you can use the following

tfpt searchcs

It brings up a dialog (like following) that allows you to search Change Sets by comment text amongst other things

[image]

Answer (score 2):

PowerTools are a great way (See other answer), here is the Quick and dirty way:

From the "View History"-Window:

1. Select all relevant Changesets you want to search
2. Press CTRL+C to copy to clipboard
3. Paste in Text editor
4. Use search function there